# Simplest way to filter value from generic List in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes. The first one is *Person*, and the second one is *Student* (which inherits from Person). I want to filter a generic *List* and find all **Students** which grades are **higher than 7**. I came up with the following solution:

```cs
class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

class Student : Person
{
    public decimal Grade {get; set;}
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(new Person() {Name="John"});
        people.Add(new Student() {Name="Joe", Grade=6});
        people.Add(new Student() {Name="Jane", Grade=8});

        people.Where(delegate (Person person) {
            var student = person as Student;
            return student != null && student.Grade > 7;
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to filter this list?

Comment: Simpler? `.Where(person => ...)` ;)

Comment: A little code review: Why is `Grade` a `decimal` and not an `int`? Does it make sense to have a `Grade` of 7.5?

Comment: @Pragmateek The *person* parameter is of type Person, and the Person class doesn't have the member Grade. If you try this way, the code will not even compile.

Comment: @KendallFrey according to what I had in mind, it makes sense. But if you just think about this snippet of code, I agree with you when you say *int* is better.

Comment: @EduardodeMatos: I mean you don't have to specify *delegate(...)* you can use a **lambda**, check *Hogan* code. :)

Comment: @Pragmateek - You're absolutely right! I didn't realize it was possible to use blocks with lambdas.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The only improvement I see is using `OfType`, like this

```
var result = people.OfType<Student>().Where(s => s.Grade > 7);
```

...and my syntax is simpler... but that is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Cute, +1. Just to be pedantic: should be a little slower no because you add one more tube in the pipeline?

Comment: @Pragmateek - not sure about that because of type should be the same "slowness" as the "as" statement.  Remember also that Linq is lazy.

Comment: @Hogan - It's not only simpler than mine, but returns an Enumerable<Student> as well. Very cool!

Comment: @Pragmateek Slower? You have three students you are filtering through! Worry about speed at this level when you have 100,000 students and you actually feel slowness in the system. Dont be premature in your optimizations.

Comment: @steve: it was a general remark, of course in this case this is not an issue. It's why I've specified "pedantic". :)

Comment: @steve, - I totally disagree with comment -- you have to consider speed or you end up with systems that don't work and end up hiring me to come in and fix them.  Sure, anything can be over designed, including optimization, but that is where software development is an art -- knowing when to worry and when not to.  To assume the original poster only has 3 records to filter is a mistake -- clearly this was a simplified question.

Comment: @Hogan you can't talk speed unless you have numbers. There's no speed comparison tests that have been run here. In theory theoretical speed is the same as actual speed, but in actuality they are different. But I digress from the main point. Unit test => Performance metrics => Refactor => Compare

Comment: @steve - I can talk speed without numbers -- eg: bubble sort is slower than quick sort.  I'll ignore further trolling.

Comment: @Hogan Um... that's because bubble sort vs. quick sort is a thoroughly researched comparison with a lot of ... well ... numbers behind it. Bubble sort CAN beat quick sort under certain circumstances. On further reading my first post was more aggressive than I like, so to make up for it by taking my own medicine. I ran some tests and posted some results as an answer :)

Comment: @Pragmateek It does appear to be somewhat slower :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a few different ways of doing it, with some relative performance numbers:

**Initial**

```
people.Where(delegate(Person person)
{
    var student = person as Student;
    return student != null && student.Grade > 7m;
});
```

**Initial Modified**
(same speed as Initial)

```
people.Where(p =>
{
    var student = p as Student;
    return student != null && student.Grade > 7m;
});
```

**OfType**
(40-52% SLOWER than Initial)

```
people.OfType<Student>().Where(s => s.Grade > 7m)
```

**Foreach**
(9-16% faster than Initial)

```
var results = new List<Student>();
foreach (var person in people)
{
    var student = person as Student;
    if (student != null && student.Grade > 7m)
    {
         results.Add(student);
    }
}
```

**For**
(12-18% faster than initial)

```
var results = new List<Student>();
for (var idxPerson = 0; idxPerson < people.Count; idxPerson++)
{
    var student = people[idxPerson] as Student;
    if (student != null && student.Grade > 7m)
    {
        results.Add(student);
    }
}
```

### To get the performance numbers, I:

- Ran a control test that did nothing
- Timed each of the functions 100 times over a List with 10 to 1,000,000 elements
- Subtracted the control time from each tests time (to make the results more accurate)
- Each function used the same random data set and ToList was used to force the enumerator to run

Of course, these are just performance numbers on my machine, you'll have to test on real-world data to get actual results as the distribution of Students vs. People, the average grade of the student, etc. will cause a lot of variation in the timings.

Comment: nice work, were all elements students?  That is what these numbers look like to me.

Comment: about 50% students, 50% person

Answer (score 1):

```
people.RemoveAll(p => p.Grade <= 7);
```