# Select elements of certain type from list (c#)

Tags: c#, list, oop

I have a list of "traps" in my main class. In the subclass "Flame" I want to delete certain elements from that list. The problem is, how do I select these elements? Trap does have other sublasses with different attributes.

This is what I got so far (code simplified, from "Flame.cs"):

```
public override Boolean collide()
{
    var flames = form1.traps.Where(trap => trap.ID == ID);
    foreach (Flame f in flames)
    {
        if (f.pos > pos)
        {
            form1.traps.Remove(f);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I feel like I should know this, but atm I'm stuck :/

Comment: Have you looked at the `typeof` operator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to filter value from generic List in C# using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255942/simplest-way-to-filter-value-from-generic-list-in-c-sharp-using-linq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method.

```
public override Boolean collide()
{
    var flames = form1.traps.Where(trap => trap.ID == ID)
                            .OfType<Flame>()
                            .Where(f => f.pos > pos)
                            .ToList();

    foreach (Flame flame in flames)
    {
        form1.traps.Remove(flame);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: the return value hast to stay "true".

Comment: I get a System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly

```
form1.traps = form1.traps.OfType<Flame>()
             .Where(trap => trap.ID == ID && trap.pos <= pos)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Problem: "Trap" does not have "pos", only "Flame" does

Comment: I think you meant `Where` not `Select`.

Comment: @Urinprobe if you had posted those classes, we wouldn't have answered blindly.

Comment: They have a lot of code, I wanted to spare you reading all that ;)