# How to pass in a list of System.Type into a method?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to pass in a list of `System.Type` into a method. Not *instances* but `Type`'s.

Now there's a catch: I wish to restrict the `Type` by an interface.

For example, imagine i have this...

```
public interface IFoo
public class Cat : IFoo
public class Dog : IFoo
```

then this..

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<Type> foos)
```

but only allow `Cat`'s and `Dog`'s and not anything else.

Usually, I do this:

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<IFoo> foos)
```

but that is asking for some foo *instances*, which is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sadly you can't.  But at runtime you can check you got the right thing, eg. typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(foo.GetType())

Comment: it's true you can't but I always use the extension method OfType() when I want to limit my collections.  see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263768/select-elements-of-certain-type-from-list-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your method only wants a list of instances (objects) that implement `IFoo`.  If so then use `IEnumerable<IFoo>`; as in:

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<IFoo> foos) { ... }
```

**Update**

There is no way to declare that the method only accepts a list of `Type`s that implement an `interface`.  You need to do the validation in your own code.

```
if (!foos.Any(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IFoo)))
   throw new ArgumentException(...);
```

Comment: Nope. I just edited my question as you answered this :)

Comment: I would suggest `if (foos.Any(t => !t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IFoo)))) { /* blow up */ }`

Comment: @rossipedia Either is okay, however you need to drop the 1st `!`

Comment: Answer does not constrain to cats and dogs only

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void MyMethod<T>(Type theType) where T : ICat {}

ICat icat = new Class2();

//This will not work because its the wrong type
IDog idog = new Class2();

MyMethod<ICat>(icat.GetType());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T theType) where T : List<Cat>, List<Dog>
```

Comment: Um - this is accepting _instances_ though? not `Type`'s?? (and by the way, it should be `where T : IFoo`).

Comment: OP says cats and dogs, not anything else.

Comment: Ok, regardless of the interpretation .. you're answer is still acepting _instances_ IMO and not `Type`'s.

Comment: This is what OP "means" by the question. The type constraint is the crux of the issue. It is not possible to pass a non instance as an argument.